# <li> with 2 elements not align properly why?

Tags: html, css, less

Hi I am struggling to align my numbers under my images they don't want to be aligned. this is a list and in the each line there an image and a number.

```
.category_icon           { height:100px; width:300px; position:absolute; left:350px; top:150px;
        ul                   { list-style:none; height:70px; width:220px; 
            li               { display: inline; margin-right: 4px; width:65px; height:90px;
                img          { width:65px; height:64px;}
                span         { font-family:Tahoma; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; position:absolute; bottom:7px; width:64px; }
            }
        }
    }



<div class="category_icon">
<ul>
    <li><img src="<%=atm.buttonPath%>/family_category_btn.png" alt="" /><span>346</span></li>
    <li><img src="<%=atm.buttonPath%>/camping_category_btn.png" alt="" /><span>12</span></li>
    <li><img src="<%=atm.buttonPath%>/cooking_category_btn.png" alt="" /><span>546</span></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks you if someone can help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[**solution with text below**](http://jsfiddle.net/faBjF/1/)  
 [**solution with centralised text below**](http://jsfiddle.net/faBjF/2/)

for images, you always have to change their `diplay` properties before you start playing around with them....add the same here and `li` to `display: inline-block; that would help`

To do :

```
li {
    display: inline-block; /*changed */
    margin-right: 4px;
    width:65px;
    height:90px;
    text-align:center;
}
img {
    display:block; /*added */
    width:65px;
    height:64px;
}
```

**PS :** I am not aware of `LESS`...so gave you a generalized solution

Comment: He's using LESS (I can only tell because of the tag.. :P)

Comment: woops....there was no tag for LESS...let OP get back to me on this...then i might be able to help further!!!! :)

Comment: Yes I forgot to it on the forum but it is on my code. this is a css problem not a syntax.

Comment: Thanks but now the numbers are on the left

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Qm6Bm/

```
.category_icon {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 350px;
    top: 150px;

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        height: 70px;
        width: 220px;

        li {
            display: inline-block; /* CHANGED */
            margin-right: 4px;
            width: 65px;
            height: 90px;
            text-align: center; /* ADDED */

            img {
                display: block; /* ADDED */
                width: 65px;
                height: 64px;
                margin-bottom: 8px; /* ADDED */
            }

            span {
                font-family: Tahoma;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 12px;
                /* Removed positioning and width */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made the `li` an inline-block and the `img` a `block`. This means the image will push the text (from the span) under it. Then, by putting `text-align: center` in the `li`, that text (from the span) is centred nicely.

I put `margin-bottom: 8px` on your `img` just like how you had the span's `bottom: 8px` :P